# Difference between answer and comment

Tags: support, comments, answers, not-an-answer

What is, here on the Stack Exchange platform, the difference between an answer and a comment? I answered a post (first post) and somebody told me it was a comment not an answer, even though it sounded like an answer to me.

Comment: Did you answer the question or ask a question to the question?

Comment: The initial question was about "does anyone know a software that can bla bla", I just suggested a software saying "have you tried bla bla".

Comment: Oh wait a second, yeah I said "have you tried bla bla?"  but it was not a real question, maybe this is the problem

Comment: That's not really a duplicate but it's useful anyway

Comment: This is my case. Thanks a lot I'm going to fix that!